# How to convert a date in columns to date serial number in Excel?

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

Assume you have a list of dates and times (24 hours) in several columns, and want to convert them to the Excel date serial number: is there a function to do this? (In this way, the dates and times can be represented on a time scale in a graph.)

| year | month | day | hour | minute | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 01 | 01 | 10 | 30 | "101" |
| 2020 | 01 | 02 | 09 | 00 | "203" |
| 2022 | 05 | 17 | 01 | 15 | "5050" |

The Excel date serial numbers are made up in this example.

Comment: `=DATE(A1,B1,C1)+TIME(D1,E1,0)`

Comment: If you enter the (correct) formula mentioned above into a cell, chances are Excel will immediately apply the `Date` format to that cell. I.e. You'll see `1/1/2020` rather than the underlying serial number. Select the cell, click `Ctrl + 1` to open the `Format Cells` dialog box and select "General" or "Number" to get `43831.4375` etc.

Comment: @SpectralInstance Exactly what I was looking for! Could you repeat your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data start in the first row

```
=DATE(A1,B1,C1)+TIME(D1,E1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert Date in columns to date serial number you can use the function

=value(text)

select the cell or column range with the date to be converted using the value(text) function.